# Updating clob column in oracle with CLOB value

Tags: java, sql, oracle, hibernate

i want to update a column is CLOB type, the method is below;

```
public boolean formVeriGuncelleSil(String sql) throws VeritabaniException {
        try {
            Session session = getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
            SQLQuery query = session.createSQLQuery(sql);
            query.executeUpdate();
            return true;
        } catch (RuntimeException e) {
            throw new VeritabaniException(e, VERIGUNCELLEMEEXCEPTION, "FID_01_02_01");
        }
    }
```

**The sql string;**

```
UPDATE K1FORM_LISTGRID3 SET TEXTAREA4=oracle.sql.CLOB@77df8d, TEXTT5='ANAFORM',ANATABLO='1', OLUSTURAN_KULLANICI='184' WHERE ID=1
```

i get "java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-01729: database link name expected" error

How can i fix this sql. Pls help.

Comment: Fix what? Do you get an error message?

Comment: Yes, i get "java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-01729: database link name expected" error and my sql query "UPDATE K1SSS_LISTGRID3 SET TEXTAREA4=oracle.sql.CLOB@77df8d,TEXTT5='deneme',ANATABLO='1',OLUSTURAN_KULLANICI='184' WHERE ID=23"

Comment: Use [PreparedStatements](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html) and the `setClob` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oracle is interpreting this SQL

```
SET TEXTAREA4=oracle.sql.CLOB@77df8d
```

as a database link because of the **@** symbol, but it does not matter anyway, because all you're doing here is trying to set the value of the column to the **toString** of the CLOB, which is not what you intend.

Your code sample does not really outline where the problem is because the method is just a general utility to execute the passed SQL, but I suggest 1 of 2 things:

1. Go with [GriffeyDog](https://stackoverflow.com/users/442451/griffeydog)'s suggestion and switch to using a PreparedStatement where you bind the CLOB using PreparedStatement.setClob.
2. If you are using the Oracle 11g+ JDBC driver, you can set the value of a CLOB column using a simple Java String.